# get Curl from httpcomponent call

Tags: curl, apache-httpcomponents

Who know how get curl from httpComponent call?

```
 CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
 URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
 builder.setScheme("http").setHost("localhost:8080/AppDev")
 .setPath("/rest/user/authenticate/")
 .setParameter("username", "joe")
 .setParameter("password", "123456");
 URI uri = builder.build();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri);
 CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

i want to get curl from that execute.

some advice?